# Print user inputs from 2D array using another class in Java?

Tags: java, class

I am trying to print user inputs in another class in Java. I have made a chessboard which asks the user to input strings on the board, and then, when these strings are printed on screen, I would like the output to be "You have placed piece [name] at coordinate [coordinate]". I am trying to do this in another class rather in the main method, but what I have tried so far doesn't seem to work. Here's my code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChessBoard
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char rows = 'a';
        String spot;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] grid = new String [8][8];

        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++, rows++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < grid[i].length; col++);
            String input = null;              // will be changed to a valid position
            boolean validCoordinate = false;   // will be true if position is valid
            while ( ! validCoordinate) {
                System.out.println("Enter a coordinate (for example, a5): ");
                input = scanner.next();
                validCoordinate = input.matches("[a-h][1-8]");
            };
            // now we now that the input is valid
            int row = input.charAt(0) - 'a';
            int col = input.charAt(1) - '1';
            String temp = input + " - ";
            System.out.println("Insert your piece:");
            input = scanner.next();
            grid[row][col] = temp + input;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
     }
}
```

So what I'd like to do is have a new class that uses that last print line to instead print the desired output that I mentioned earlier. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChessBoard1
{
    public static  void main(String[] args)
    {
        userInputs input = new userInputs();
        showInput show = new showInput();

        String grid[][] = input.takeInput();
        show.show(grid);
    }
}



public class userInputs
{
    public String[][] takeInput()
    {
        char rows = 'a';
        String spot;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] grid = new String [8][8];

        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++, rows++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid[i].length; col++) ;
            String input = null;              // will be changed to a valid position
            boolean validCoordinate = false;   // will be true if position is valid
            while (!validCoordinate) {
                System.out.println("Enter a coordinate (for example, a5): ");
                input = scanner.next();
                validCoordinate = input.matches("[a-h][1-8]");
            }
            ;
            // now we now that the input is valid
            int row = input.charAt(0) - 'a';
            int col = input.charAt(1) - '1';
            String temp = input + " - ";
            System.out.println("Insert your piece:");
            input = scanner.next();
            grid[row][col] = temp + input;
        }
        return  grid;
    }
}



public class showInput {

    public void show(String [][] inputs)
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<inputs.length ; i++){
            for(int j=0  ; j < inputs[0].length ; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 separate files userInputs and showInput but they it says that they should still be declared in a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong to write main Function in every class, the program uses the main function to start from it, So you should write it only in the main project class and call inside it the other classes.
Your code should be:

```
package com.company;

public class ChessBoard
{
    public static  void main(String[] args)
    {
        userInputs input = new userInputs();
        showInput show = new showInput();

        String grid[][] = input.takeInput();
        show.show(grid);
    }
}
```

and other classes in separate files like:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class userInputs
{
    public String[][] takeInput()
    {
        char rows = 'a';
        String spot;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] grid = new String [8][8];

        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++, rows++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid[i].length; col++) ;
            String input = null;              // will be changed to a valid position
            boolean validCoordinate = false;   // will be true if position is valid
            while (!validCoordinate) {
                System.out.println("Enter a coordinate (for example, a5): ");
                input = scanner.next();
                validCoordinate = input.matches("[a-h][1-8]");
            }
            ;
            // now we now that the input is valid
            int row = input.charAt(0) - 'a';
            int col = input.charAt(1) - '1';
            String temp = input + " - ";
            System.out.println("Insert your piece:");
            input = scanner.next();
            grid[row][col] = temp + input;
        }
        return  grid;
    }
}
```

and another class to output:

```
package com.company;

public class showInput {

    public void show(String [][] inputs)
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<inputs.length ; i++){
            for(int j=0  ; j < inputs[0].length ; j++)
            {
                //Print Your Data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I make new files for each of these sections? How can I call upon them in the main code? Thanks a lot, this is really helpful!

Comment: when you create new java classes in the current project they can see each others, you only need to make an object firstly from the class you need as i wrote in the main class, and then uses the functions inside it using '.' operation (obj.function()). read the main function carefully to understand more.

Comment: In the first two lines in main function i created two object from the classes that created, and use every object to use the function inside it, for more advice you need to study classes more from any tutorials to understand it well

Comment: I don't see them, are you talking about in the chessBoard class?

Comment: No, in the main function first to lines for object Creation (Using the 'new' for create the obj.)

Comment: What's a good way of printing out the Array in the other file? Ive tried "System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));" Which gives me errors which say "cannot find symbol" for Arrays and grid, which I'm assuming is because it's not in the main file. Any way to fix this?

Comment: print it index by index, Use "System.out.println(grid[i][j]);" in the nested loop

Comment: In place  "//Print Your Dat"a comment try write: System.out.println(grid[i][j]); and see the output

Comment: it says it cant find the symbol grid? Probably because it is in the other class?

Comment: no, sorry instead of grid write inputs[i][j], because the parameter now is inputs

Answer (score 1):

Like @Atef Magdy said, You should have one class which holds all the data and functions
and a main class which executes the functions.

and the explanation for this error ( it states that using public int is an "illegal start" to the expression, and that it needs a ";" after it?) I have seen that you made the 2d Array of Type String?

```java
String[] [] grid = new String [8][8];
```

and then returning it as a 1D Array of Type int?

```java
public int[] getGrid(){
return grid.clone();
}
```

I should say that this is the source of this error. You should change the 'int[]' to 'string[][]'

if there is any error please reply to this answer!

Comment: All good now I just need to find a way to print the array from a new class, thanks!

Comment: @WanttoBeScripter147 you can create object and reference that array ex :  dataClass data = new dataClass(); and then System.out.println(data.MyArray);

Comment: Thanks! At the top i've added 2 new objects, one class is for the user input and one is for the output. at the bottom of the edit is what my output code looks like. Do I input dataClass data in the for loop? Or remove that completely?

Comment: @WanttoBeScripter147 is this your expected result?```                                                                       Enter a coordinate (for example, a5): 
                    a1
Insert your piece:
                   king
a1 - king
Enter a coordinate (for example, a5):